# Midje: having single actual value with multiple arrow functions

Tags: clojure, midje

Put simply, I would like the code shown below to behave how one could think it should behave, e.g. defining the left-hand side value (here as a trivial anonymous associative collection) just once and applying multiple different arrow functions (asserions) to it in a clean and idiomatic way:

```
  (deftest test-test
    (fact "some-fact"
      {:a 1 :b 2}
      =>
          (contains {:a odd?}))
      =not=>
          (contains {:a even?})
    )
```

This code obviously doesn't work: only `=>` arrow actually asserts and `=not=>` is irrelevant (e.g. if we change `even?` to `odd?` there the test still passes).

Maybe it's as simple as wrapping in `let` or using `def`, but being new to Clojure I would like to know what is the preferred way.

Comment: If you're new to Clojure, I'd strongly recommend avoiding Midje. It is not idiomatic, it is not widely used, tooling/editor support for it isn't great these days, and you'll have a hard time getting support since it's mostly abandoned at this point (the original maintainer moved on to another tech).

Comment: @SeanCorfield that's good to know! Unfortunately, it is a part of a legacy codebase I have to deal with. While at it, and while being OK with a purely opinion based answer, what would you consider a state-of-the-art testing framework for Clojure nowadays?

Comment: At work we use a mixture of plain ol' `clojure.test` and `expectations.clojure.test`, which is a `clojure.test`-compatible version of the Classic Expectations library originally created by Jay Fields (which I now maintain, since Jay stepped away and we were committed to using it at that point). https://github.com/clojure-expectations/clojure-test I don't think Expectations is widely used but I like the expressiveness of it. We have about 26k lines of tests at work (out of 143k lines of Clojure in total).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every *checkable* must have a left-hand side, an arrow, and a right-hand side, so this code won't work. I also think that Midje is intended as the unit testing library (testing result of one function for different inputs) and you should instead use [Spec](https://github.com/clojure/spec.alpha) or [Malli](https://github.com/metosin/malli) for testing data structures.

That said, I think you can achieve that result in several ways:

You can of course repeat your left-hand side value twice:

```
(fact "some-fact"
      {:a 1 :b 2} => (contains {:a odd?})
      {:a 1 :b 2} =not=> (contains {:a even?}))
=> true
```

Or insert it into `let`:

```
(let [my-map {:a 1 :b 2}]
  (fact "some-fact"
        my-map => (contains {:a odd?})
        my-map =not=> (contains {:a even?})))
=> true
```

You can use `every-checker`:

```
(fact "some-fact"
      {:a 1 :b 2}
      => (every-checker (contains {:a odd? :b even?})
                        #(not (some-> (:a %) even?))))
=> true
```

You can write some macro, which would transform that code exactly as you wish (if you're really new to Clojure, think twice if you really need to do that):

```
(defmacro mfact [doc o & args]
  `(fact ~doc
         ~@(mapcat (fn [[x y]] (list o x y))
                   (partition 2 args))))

(mfact "some-fact"
       {:a 1 :b 2}
       =>
       (contains {:a odd?})
       =not=>
       (contains {:a even?}))
=> true
```

Comment: Such a areat answer! I really appreciate you've shown the macro approach, while I will hold of with such wizardry for now, for a newbie it is certainly interesting to see them put to such a simple but pragmatic use.